# If a union of disjoint submanifolds is open, is then at least one of the members open?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a topological manifold and let $\{Y_i : Y_i\subset X\}$ be a finite family of submanifolds (without boundary and equipped with the subspace topology, of course). Assume that all submanifolds $Y_i$ are pairwise disjoint. If the (finite) union $\bigcup_i Y_i$ is an open submanifold in $X$, does this imply that there is at least one  $Y_i$ which is an open submanifold in $X$? I would appreciate a brief proof if possible.

EDIT: I change the question in the following way: First, I asked if all $Y_i$ are open. It was shown in the comments that this is not always true. Now, I would like to know if at least one $Y_i$ is open.

Comment: Or just $Y_1=(0,1], Y_2=(1,2)$?

Comment: @ Sassateli Giulio, I reformulated the question so that it is makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that a true submanifold $Y\subset X$ is open if and only if $\dim(Y)=\dim(X)$. If you allow submanifolds of different dimensions, then $X=(-1,1)$, $Y_0=(-1,0)$, $Y_1=\{0\}$, $Y_2=(0,1)$ shows that the answer is no.

Comment: Right. However, can we always claim that at least one of the submanifolds $Y_i$ always must be open?

Comment: Yes, in the finite union at least one of the submanifolds has the same dimension as $X$ and thus has to be open.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I expect, as well. May I ask about a formal argument? It seems obvious, but what is the formal justification?

Comment: A submanifold of lower dimension evidently has empty interior. Hence the interior of its complement is open and dense and the intersection of finitely many open dense subsets in a topological manifold is open and dense. (You can quote Baire's theorem for that, but this is kind of an overkill.) So you cannot write a manifold as a finite union of lower dimensional submanifolds. Hence in your union, one of the $Y_i$ has to have the same dimension as $X$ and hence is open.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. This explains the whole business much clearer. However, I would like to clarify two things. The interior of the submanifold $Y$ of $X$ of lower dimension is empty. Hence, its complement in $X$ is open and dense in $X$. OI agree with this. But the interior of the complement is not necessarily dense, or am I missing something? Second, where exactly do we use the fact that the intersection of finitely many open dense sets is open and dense in $X$?

Comment: If the complement open, then it agrees with its interior. For the second part, the complement of the union of the $Y_i$ is the intersection of the complements of the $Y_i$. So if all the $Y_i$ have empty interior, also their union has empty interior.

Comment: I made a mistake. I apologise for that. I meant: If the interior of $Y$ is empty, then its complement in $X$ is only dense but not necessarily open. Its interior is open but it is not necessarily dense. That was my problem. You seem to claim that the interior of the complement of $Y$ is open and dense and I do not see it immediately.

Comment: If you look at the definition, it is evident that the complement of a submanifold of lower dimension is open.

Comment: I think that this statement is not accurate because that would imply that the submanifold of lower dimension is closed which is not necessary. The submanifold of lower dimension could be locally closed, for example. For instance, the strata of a stratified manifold are locally closed submanifolds many of which are of lower dimension.

Comment: I agree, but looking at submanifold charts, you still see that the interior of the complement of a submanifold of lower dimension is dense.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! Where do I look at submanifold charts-in the submanifold of lower dimension or in the complement?

Comment: The only remaining question is whether any point of the submanifold has a neighborhood that meets the interior of the complement of the submanifold. Taking a submanifold chart containing that point, this is obvious.

Comment: I disagree again. Every neighbourhood of every point on the submanifold of lower dimension should meet the interior of the complement of the submanifold. Only then, the interior of the complement is dense. It is not enough to show the existence of just one neighbourhood.

Comment: It is obvious, since in the submanifold chart any neighborhood of a point in the submanifold contains a small ball around this point in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Let me repeat what you are doing so I am sure that I understand you correctly. Since we have the partition $X=\overline{Y}\coprod Int(X\setminus Y)$, where $\overline{Y}$ is the closure of $Y$ in $X$ and $Int(X\setminus Y)$ is the interior of the complement of $Y$ in $X$, in order to show that $Int(X\setminus Y)$ is dense in $X$, it suffices to show that $Y\subset\overline{Int(X\setminus Y)}$ because then $\overline{Y}\subset\overline{Int(X\setminus Y)}$. This is your proof idea, right? However, in the above you only show that $Y\subset\overline{X\setminus Y}$ which is not enough.

Comment: Ok. For a coordinate chart $\phi:U\to B_r(\phi(y))\subset\mathbb C^n$, $r>0$,  of $X$ at a point $y$ on the submanifold $Y$ of lower dimension $m$, the intersection $U\cap Int(X\setminus Y)\neq\emptyset$ if and only if $B_r(\phi(y))\cap Int(B_r(\phi(y))\setminus\mathbb C^m)=Int(B_r(\phi(y))\setminus\mathbb C^m)\neq\emptyset$. The last inequality follows from the fact that $\mathbb C^n$ is topologically regular. Is this what you are assuming implicitly in your last comment?

Comment: To use balls, you need a metric space, which is trivially normal hence regular, so this is not an implicit assumption but a fact.

Comment: Thanks! So, you use the regularity of $\mathbb C^n$ to show that a point $y$ in the submanifold $Y$ has a $U$ neighbourhood in $X$ which intersects the interior of $X\setminus Y$. Correct?

Comment: yes, that's the argument that is used.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the discussion!

Comment: @ Andreas Cap If instead of a finite union $\cup_iY_i$ of submanifolds $Y_i$ in a smooth manifold $X$, we have a union of an infinite but countable number of submanifolds $Y_i$ of X such that $\cup_iY_i$ is open in $X$, can we infer that there is at least one $Y_i$ which is open in $X$? I think that would be a plausible generalisation of the finite case which we discussed a few months ago.